# Amazon Product API returns empty cart after going to Purchase URL in Chrome

Tags: php, rest, amazon-product-api

I have a page that contains many products. I am using the API to add/remove/modify items from the cart. Everything is setup correctly and works perfectly fine in every browser but Chrome. If I add items to a cart and then go to the purchase URL for that cart. When I go back to my page and refresh it the cart is empty and the API returns an empty cart. This only happens after going to the purchase URL in chrome for a cart.

**This is the call made when items are in the cart and I refresh the page (before going to the purchase URL):**

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=REMOVED&AssociateTag=3911-REMOVED&ItemId=B000002H6C&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Variations&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2013-10-28T21%3A46%3A11Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=WzgoNcNmZgkt45NFuR62upbYHm0Qoy5%2B7E9B6nUthFk%3D
```

**This is the returned info from the above request:**

[image: cart-items]

**This is the call made AFTER going to the purchase URL and then refreshing the page:**

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=REMOVED&AssociateTag=3911-REMOVED&ItemId=B000002H6C&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Variations&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2013-10-28T21%3A47%3A12Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=3cJo0Nxp1LMPrAyB%2FpBnu2LmINC0B%2FcxgxFLq%2FtCkME%3D
```

**This is the returned info from the above request:**

[image: cart-empty]

This issue only happens in Chrome and I am not sure why this is occuring.

Comment: Have yout tested in more the one machine in Chrome or just yours? Sounds like some browser especific configuration.

Comment: I have, I have testing in 4 different machines including Mac.

Comment: I've find some of yours same issue over the internet in previous versions of the chrome. it looks like a Chrome bug but every where I find it people answer that the problem solved itself, matbe with a Chrome update. You should post thhis at the Google Chrome fórum.

Comment: I don't see any discussion on this. Did you happen to see a forum post where this issue came up with Chrome?

Comment: [link 1](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=10570&tstart=15)

Comment: [link 2](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/nkNsi5WQ8VM) withoud answer this one

Comment: [link 3](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161500) from issues of chromiun

Comment: Thanks, Jorge. The first link seems most relevant, unfortunately it does not have an answer. I did post a question in the Chrome forums just now hopefully someone has some insight. Thanks again.